# If $k$ is a finite field and $\omega:k^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is a homomorphism s.t. $\omega^2\neq 1$, why does $\sum_{d\in k^*} \omega(d)^2 = 0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

If $k$ is a finite field and $\omega:k^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is a homomorphism s.t. $\omega^2\neq 1$, why does $\sum_{d\in k^*} \omega(d)^2 = 0$?

Came up in a computation for a problem with characters. Since $k^*$ is a cyclic group, I think $\omega(d)$ should be a root of unity. Since $\omega^2 \neq 1$, there is a generator $x$ for $k^*$ such that $\omega(x)$ is an $n$-th root of unity, $n>2$.

I am not sure where to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that if $\chi\colon k^*\to\Bbb C^*$ is a homomorphism that isn't identically $1$, then $\sum_{d\in k^*} \chi(d)=0$? (This is often called the "orthogonality" property of abelian group characters.) Your question is just this fact applied to $\chi=\omega^2$.

Comment: @GregMartin I see, you are just applying the fact that $\chi$ is an irreducible character (as a homomorphism of an abelian group) and hence orthogonal to the trivial character.